# Why do no crash reports appear in Xcode's device log for my iPad Mini?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, ipad-mini

When I connect one of my devices (an iPad mini), open Xcode's Devices window, select my device and then click the View Device Logs button I see only an empty list. No crash reports are listed.  I know there are crash reports because I can see them in Diagnostics & Usage in the mini's Settings.

In this view, clicking View Device Logs always shows my crash reports when I have my other devices connected.

Attached is an image of what things look like normally. "This Device" is selected and there is a list of crash reports.  For my Mini that list is completely empty even though "This Device" has been selected.

[image]

Comment: Is the Mini configured for development with Xcode? Is it running an appropriate system? Have you set the Mini to trust this computer? There are a lot of things you have not told us!

Comment: I hadn't thought about the "trust this computer" setting.  Will look that up.  But what do you mean by "running an appropriate system" and "configured for development with Xcode"?

Comment: When you plug a device into your computer, Xcode doesn't really see it until you provision for it - for example, you start with a project _in Xcode_ and try to build and run _from Xcode_ onto that device. Otherwise, the device is a total stranger, and I'm thinking that maybe that's the problem.

Comment: It's not a total stranger.  I used the Devices screen to load the adhoc version on it that generated the crash report I'm trying to see.  I'll verify that the device's id is in the provisioning profile though.  What about your comment about "running an appropriate system"?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm thinking that, say, Xcode 6 might not like your Mini if it's running iOS 9, for example. Really, what I'm getting at is simply that you should try to think of ways in which the mini differs from the other devices for which this does work.

Comment: @matt -- Hmm... Maybe so.  It's true the Mini has an iOS version that would require me to upgrade to Xcode 6.3 (and thus Yosemite also) but as mentioned I figured out how to get ad hoc builds on it despite the warning. I'll hope it's the "Trust this computer?" since I cannot jack with upgrading my OS (I'm trying to release an app).  If I figure it out I'll contact you so you can add an answer and I can mark it correct.  Mini's not in my possession right now.

Comment: Ok, it trusts my computer. The Mini is using iOS 8.4 but since I haven't upgraded to Yosemite I'm still using Xcode 6.2.  Is that the problem?  And how can I get crash reports off this device without upgrading?

Comment: Am able to view the crash logs with iOS 8.1 (ipad mini)and Xcode 6.4, but when I upgraded my iOS to 8.4 am not able to view any crash logs in xcode 6.4 and am able to view logs inside the mini diagnostics.